# What percentage of buildings in Greater London were destroyed during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, london

I would like to do as direct as possible comparison with the bomb damage which occurred in German cities. This is listed as percentage buildings destroyed in Max Hasting's Bomber Command. I already know the tonnage of Bombs dropped on London and have heard a rough figure of 1 million buildings destroyed although I'm unsure of the original source of this and it seems too high to me.

Comment: The figure will depend on your definition of '_destroyed_'.  For London, "[More than 70,000 buildings were completely demolished, and another 1.7 million were damaged](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/phenomena/2016/05/18/bomb-damage-maps-reveal-londons-world-war-ii-devastation/)".

Comment: Thank you that's extremely helpful. Do you know how many buildings were in London at the time?

Comment: I don't have the figure to hand, but you might find [The London County Council Bomb Damage Maps 1939-1945](https://thamesandhudson.com/the-london-county-council-bomb-damage-maps-1939-1945-9780500518250) a useful resource if you can get hold of a copy.  You'll probably also find the sources used to create the [Bomb Sight project](http://bombsight.org/data/) web site and app useful, although they're limited to a narrower date-range.